# How to store product images in the filesystem in odoo[v8]

Tags: odoo

How can I store the product images in the filesystem instead of in the DB?

I tried adding `product_image.location` with value `file:///filestore` to my system parameters but that didn't work. Also `ir_attachment.location file:///filestore` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just set  **ir_attachment.location** to **file**

Comment: I did that but it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

to save the product images into the server file system you must write your own controller, look into the images module published by serpent, it must be give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

By default, field binary in Odoo will be save in database, whereas by default attachment will be save in filesystem.
So if you want to make field binary (example : product image) stored in filesystem, you may take a look at this forum explanation : https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/using-filesystem-for-binary-field-45127

Comment: Better summarize the contents here; the link could go stale.

Answer (score 0):

According to the web search results, you can store the product images in the filesystem instead of in the DB in odoo by following these steps:

•  Create a new system parameter with the key ir_attachment.location and the value file:///filestore in the menu Parameters -->System Parametershttps://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-store-product-images-in-the-filesystem-in-odoo-v8-73906https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-use-the-filesystem-instead-of-storing-images-in-the-database-with-base64-63108.

•  Set the data_dir path in the openerp-server.conf file to point to the directory where you want to store the fileshttps://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-store-product-images-in-the-filesystem-in-odoo-v8-73906https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-use-the-filesystem-instead-of-storing-images-in-the-database-with-base64-63108. For example, data_dir = /opt/odoo/odoo-server/files.

•  Make sure the odoo server has write access to the data_dir directory and its subdirectorieshttps://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-store-product-images-in-the-filesystem-in-odoo-v8-73906https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-use-the-filesystem-instead-of-storing-images-in-the-database-with-base64-63108. You can use the command sudo chmod 755 on Ubuntu to grant the permission.

•  Restart the odoo server and check if the product images are stored in the filestore subdirectory under the data_dir directoryhttps://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-store-product-images-in-the-filesystem-in-odoo-v8-73906https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-use-the-filesystem-instead-of-storing-images-in-the-database-with-base64-63108. The filestore subdirectory should have the same name as the database you are using.